# WooCommerce - Stop redirect to welcome screen upon plugin activation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to stop WooCommerce from redirecting the user to the welcome screen upon the plugin activation.

[image]

Does anyone have some code to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard', '__return_false' );
```

Same effect using an existing filter.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. If anyone else needs help with this the code is below.

```
//Old Solution: Stop WooCommerce redirect on activation
// function woocommerce_no_redirect_on_activation() {
//  delete_transient( '_wc_activation_redirect' );
// };
// add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_no_redirect_on_activation');
```

Edit: anikitas answer is better. I accepted their answer as the best solution:

```
//Stop WooCommerce redirect on activation
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard', '__return_false' );
```